# Baseline classifier in weka

Tags: classification, analytics, weka, data-processing

I am carrying out an analysis on my dataset in weka. I want to use 3 types of learning schemes to carry out this process: PART, JRip and J48.

Another required step is to have ZeroR as the baseline classifier. How can I declare this as my baseline classfier in Weka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as a comparison to the other learning schemes used. This is what I can make of your question anyway hope it helps.